# Is there an actionscript extension for visual studio?

Tags: actionscript-3

I prefer the VS IDE over flex builder.

Answer (score 5):

There used to be a few alternative commercial VS plugins for Flex dev but they have all disappeared. IntelliJ IDEA and the official (mostly unsupported) Adobe Flex IDE are the only commercial remaining offerings.

As suggested there is the free and opensource FlashDevelop IDE which is inspired by Visual Studio:

- http://flashdevelop.org

Comment: +1 for FlashDevelop. I'm too can't stand Flex/Flash 's IDEs and loves VS, and FD has just solved this/

Comment: your links are all 404s (except flashdevelop).  time to update this answer

Comment: Thanks @deltree, unfortunately these plugins came to the market as AS3 was already losing steam.

Answer (score 2):

Flashdevelop is also a nice program for actionscript programming.

Comment: Flash Develop does not have a SVN extension/plugin. Personally I suggest using Flex Builder and only work with actionscript projects, though it looks like the the OP is not interested in flex builder.

Comment: Just a little update as now FlashDevelop does indeed have integrated support for SVN, GIT and soon Mercurial.

Comment: Intellisense on VS is offers a lot features than FlashDevelop's code completion feature

Answer (score 2):

Yes! Code drive!

http://www.codedrive.com/

Answer (score 0):

check out the Neutron :

http://neutron.sharpstyle.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could also try FDT plugin with eclipse. Easy to intergrate SVN etc. Just expensive to buy is its main downfall.

Answer (score 0):

We will shortly launch the final version of the Amethyst Flash Platform IDE for Visual Studio. There will be a free (edit+debug) release plus a commercial release with a visual design environment, extensive code formatting, refactoring, simultaneous multi-SWF debugging, extensive IntelliSense and integration with the Flash IDE.

More info on our web site: http://www.sapphiresteel.com

best wishes

Huw Collingbourne
SapphireSteel Software

Answer (score 0):

We now have a feature list so you can compare the free version of Amethyst (Flash Platform IDE for Visual Studio) with the commercial edition: http://www.sapphiresteel.com/spip.php?page=amethyst-feature-list

Hope that helps

Huw

Answer (score 0):

Try CodeDrive - new ActionScript 3 IDE for Visual Studio. CodeDrive has its own(!) ActionScript 3 compiler with full language support. It seems to work 2-3 times faster than Flex SDK or Flash IDE.

Advanced coding features are also included - code completion, syntax coloring, error highlighting, flashlog viewer, etc.

http://www.codedrive.com/